# Healenium Implementation for Javascript WDIO

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, webdriver, self-healing

We are currently using webdriverIO version 7 for our automation. We use cucumber framework with Javascript and use npm.

We use node docker image to run the scripts via Jenkins.

We were thinking of exploring Healenium but there is limited information currently available for the same.

Any idea if Healenium can be used with WDIO and npm. Also for WDIO7, the syntax for findElement is $. Can Healenium recognize the same?

There is not much information currently available about Healenium on web.
Any help would be appreciated.